# jQuery Post function not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I get this error when trying to post a (working) API - when I post it out of my extension it works, however when I post it out of my extension in Chrome's Console i get this error:

> (my api) 403 (Token Validation Failed)

Here is the "permissions" section of my manifest.json...

```
"permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "tabs", "notifications",
"tabCapture", "http://*.roblox.com/*", "https://*.roblox.com/*",
"http://*.rbxcdn.com/*","webRequest",
"webRequestBlocking","http://*.robloxplus.com/*" ]
```

Why is it coming up with this error. My API is correct, just unsure what's happening. Also May I add, that I am posting this when a user clicks the Google chrome notification button.

Comment: Helllllllp?   PLease

Comment: It seems like the extension isn't sending a correct token to the API. Nothing to do with your permissions.

Comment: @Barmar No, I've just checked yet again. I looked in network and posted the exact same api and it worked

Comment: May I get mroe answers?