# Issue with doing a post request in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So basically my chrome extension preforms a post request on a site in which i'm currently logged on to. I do a get request on one of the pages of the site:

```
$.get('https://www.roblox.com/home',function(data)
```

in the data it show proof of me being logged in as I can see that one of the elements displays my userId as proof of login.

The issue is when I tried to preform a post request to a purchasing api to buy an item, I get an error:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST https://www.roblox.com/API/Item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID=229840030&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=35&expectedSellerId=1&userAssetID 403 (Token Validation Failed)
```

This is my code:

```
  $.post("https://www.roblox.com/API/Item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID=229840030&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=35&expectedSellerId=1&userAssetID").done(function(){
    alert('Bought!')
  });
```

My question is why do I get this error?

Comment: is there documentation on the purchase API resource? And also 403 means the server got the message but based on its content refused to service the request.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're attaching a token to the request. Tokens are usually obtained during the sign-in process and are then attached to the header of all future requests to tell the server what user is making the request.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to send request headers through?

Comment: Because if I do, I already tried sending an xcsrf token through and it gave the same error

Comment: Based from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664949/jquery-post-function-not-working-in-chrome-extension#comment57076005_34664949), one possible reason is that the extension isn't sending a correct token to the API. Nothing to do with your permissions. You may also check this [link](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/509) and see if it helps.